# Maven filtered file in jar is out of date

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a strange problem with maven. I am using the filtering option to put some version information into a properties file. I then include that in the jar file, so that "Help/About" can tell me something useful. The problem I am having is that the version in the jar file is the *previous* version. So, if, for example I run a build at 0930, and another at 0940, then the version of the properties file in the jar generated at 0940 will have a build time of 0930. I am using the buildNumber plugin as well, but this issue is present whether or not I enable it.

What is even stranger is that when I run my build from within eclipse and run the program, the "old" file shows up on help/about, but then when I "Refresh" (F5) the eclipse project and re-run the program, I get the correct version. So could it be that maven is taking the eclipse version somehow? And why do you need to "refresh" in eclipse to get it to have the most up to date version.

Anyway, my pom.xml is

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <scm>
        <url>scm:git:https://github.com/gregryork/DayOneViewer</url>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/gregryork/DayOneViewer</developerConnection>

        <tag>master</tag>
    </scm>


    <groupId>uk.co.gregreynolds</groupId>
    <artifactId>dayone</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>dayone</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <version.template.file>src/main/resources/uk/co/gregreynolds/dayone/Version.properties.template</version.template.file>
        <version.file>src/main/resources/uk/co/gregreynolds/dayone/Version.properties</version.file>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                    <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                    <revisionOnScmFailure>true</revisionOnScmFailure>
                    <format>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm}_{1}</format>
                    <items>
                        <item>timestamp</item>
                        <item>${user.name}</item>
                    </items>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>uk.co.gregreynolds.dayone.DayOneViewer</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-replacer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>replace</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <file>${version.template.file}</file>
                    <outputFile>${version.file}</outputFile>
                    <replacements>
                        <replacement>
                            <token>@buildnumber@</token>
                            <value>${buildNumber}</value>
                        </replacement>
                        <replacement>
                            <token>@buildtime@</token>
                            <value>${maven.build.timestamp}</value>
                        </replacement>
                        <replacement>
                            <token>@pomversion@</token>
                            <value>${project.version}</value>
                        </replacement>
                    </replacements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency><!-- add support for ssh/scp -->
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-replacer-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.4.0,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>replace</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.plist</groupId>
            <artifactId>dd-plist</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>swingx</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
        <site>
            <id>langurmonkey.no-ip.org</id>
            <url>scp://langurmonkey.no-ip.org/var/www/dayone/</url>
        </site>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: You know of the `filtering` resources ? Cause you don't need the replace plugin to create property files which contain the version/build time etc. Furthermore the version of the [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) is a little bit out-of-date. Apart from that how did you called your build? `mvn install`?

Comment: I am pretty new to maven, so I am not familiar with the filtering. I updated the buildnumber plugin, but, like I said, that wasn't really the issue as I was seeing the problem before I installed it. I am using the "package" target.

Comment: I have added an answer. But maven has no 'targets' it has life-cycle-phases and sometime you can use goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is to activate the filtering of your resources like this:

```
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>

    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
```

This will activate the filtering for all files which are in the folder (and subfolders) of `src/main/resources`. Sometimes you need the filtering only for a limited number of files. In such sutuations just put those files into a subfolder and change the above configuration appropriately.
Next is to define a property file (in `src/main/resources` folder) which contains all information you need like this:

version=${project.version}
  buildNumber=${buildNumber}
  buildTime=${maven.build.timestamp}

Furthermore do the configuration for the [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html) like this:

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>create</goal>
                </goals>
             </execution>
           </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                <revisionOnScmFailure>UNKNOWN</revisionOnScmFailure>
                <format>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm}_{1}</format>
                <items>
                    <item>timestamp</item>
                    <item>${user.name}</item>
                </items>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

After that you can simple remove the usuage of the maven-replacer-plugin which you don't need in such simple scenarios.

Comment: Thanks - I got rid of the replacer plugin and it all seems to work fine now.